# Safari not applying subpage class

Tags: conditional-statements, browser

In order to have different styling for different pages on my site, I have a .subpage class that I apply with a conditional to any page that's not the index.php file.  The conditional is like this:

```
<body{if segment_1} class="subpage"{/if}>
```

This code does mainly just one thing.  On the home page, my header is tall, and has multiple background images (3).  On the subpages, it is a shorter header and only uses one image.

It works just as it should on various browsers, but for whatever reason on my ipad, it wants to apply the taller header (the one for the home page) to all the subpages as well.  Its almost as if its not recognizing the conditional. If I add an ! to the conditional, I get the exact same symptom on other browsers.

Has anyone else seen this?

I'm not sure what code would be helpful to debug this, so if you want to see anything, please let me know and I'll edit to include the code.  If you would like to view the site to know what I'm talking about, its here:

[my site](http://s423839726.onlinehome.us/franklinvineyard/index.php)

I'm not sure if this is an EE problem or just a normal browser problem, and maybe I should be starting at stackoverflow, but honestly...the people here are nicer and not condescending.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a CSS specificity problem. Add `background-size:initial` into your `.subpage` ruleset so that it overrides the background-size specified in your < 900px wide media query.

Comment: thank you so much!  that fixed it.  I'm going to have to read up on background-size: initial...I have no idea why it fixed it, but it did.  thank you!!

Comment: The problem is that the shorthand `background` property in webkit does not override all the various `background-xxx` properties. Using `background-image` instead of `background` may also work.